# how do i change android soft keyboard's default language?

Tags: android

I have made android app. my client ask me that change default language at soft keyboard case by case. one case, keyboard should be English keyboard, another, Korean keyboard.

how can i do?

thx.

Comment: The user chooses the soft keyboard language.

Comment: I want to change by programming. Is it impossible?

Answer (score -2):

Android should provide there keyboard with a broadcast receiver which accepts some kind of intents to change its language. so users can use intent to access keyboard language.